# Move navigation menu to the top, below action bar Android / XML

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, android-actionbar

***Hello Stackoverflow!***

I'm designing an android application, as you see in the photo below:

[Screenshot of Application run test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2rMO.jpg)

> I cannot embed photos yet, please check the link

I have a `navigation menu` stuck bottom of the screen, I want to move this `navigation bar` to the top, `under action bar` which has *Home* title.

***I'm new to Android, thanks for the simple and full-way-to-solution responses!***

**Bottom navigation menu XML:**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_remote"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_tools"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tools_24"
    android:title="@string/title_Tools" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_notifications" />
```

**Main Activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**I found this file too named as mobile navigation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.gsm.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_tools"
        android:name="com.example.gsm.ui.tools.toolsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_Tools"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.gsm.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.gsm.ui.MapsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_maps" />
</navigation>
```

***Thanks for response***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main activity XML,in your navigation bar, change
`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
to
`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`